# WYMEditor and Rails 3.2 asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, wymeditor

I am having trouble getting WYMEditor to work correctly in Rails 3.2 production mode with the asset pipeline.  Here is my setup:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require wymeditor/jquery.wymeditor.min
//= require_tree .
```

WYMEditor files are located at `vendor/assets/javascripts/wymeditor/*`

```
# in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb just above closing </body> tag
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea').wymeditor(); 
  });
</script>
```

In development mode everything works fine.  However, after I did `rake assets:clean` and `rake assets:precompile` and started my server `rails s -e production`, the WYMEditor doesn't work anymore.  I looked in `public/assets/application.js` and it appears the WYMEditor code was included in that file.  However, the errors I get seem to indicate that WYMEditor is looking for some of its files relative to the page on which the WYMEditor is included rather than in the `public/assets/wymeditor` folder that gets created during the precompilation process:

```
Started GET "/users/lang/en.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-09 16:11:12 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/lang/en.js"):

Started GET "/users/skins/default/skin.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-09 16:11:12 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/skins/default/skin.js"):

Started GET "/users/iframe/default/wymiframe.html" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-09 16:11:12 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/iframe/default/wymiframe.html"):

[snipped stack traces and more similar error messages]
```

After much Googling I came across a page that seemed to indicate that WYMEditor is unhappy when its code is included in `application.js` and that it needs to be in its own separate folder.  However, I don't know if this is actually true or not.  What would be the recommended way to get WYMEditor to work in production mode?

Comment: To get this to work I bypassed the asset pipeline.  To do this I copied the WYMEditor files to `public/wymeditor/*` and put this HTML directly in my layout: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/wymeditor/jquery.wymeditor.min.js"></script>`.  Not sure if this is a good idea, but I needed this to work ASAP.

Comment: In case you figured out any better solution than the one you posted here, please update your answer. The solution you mentioned seems to work, though. Thank you!